# Terraform : 'INVALID_JSON_DESCRIPTION: Illegal unquoted character

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have a Terraform step_function script that calls a Lambda function to send email. I want to send the body of the email as a variable like that :

```
  data "template_file" "start_es_email" {
    template = "${file("email_template/start_es.html")}"
  }

  data "template_file" "start_template" {
    template = "${file("step_function/start_stepfunction.json")}"

    vars = {
      aws_region            = "${var.aws_region}",
      ses_sender            = "${var.ses_sender}"
      ses_destination_email = "${var.ses_destination_emails}"
      ses_body_html         = "${data.template_file.start_es_email.rendered}"
    }
  }
```

This is content of the start_es.html file, it's a just a simple HTML content :

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>ElasticSearch cluster started and ready</h1>
<p>
The ElasticSearch cluster has started and ready to use
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the state function resource :

```
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "start_cluster" {
  name     = "start-es-sfn-${var.environment}"
  role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.step_function_iam_role.arn}"

  definition = "${data.template_file.start_template.rendered}"
}
```

And this is what i have in the state function json file :

```
"SendSuccessEmail": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "${lambda_notification}",
      "Parameters": {
        "SES_SENDER": "${ses_sender}",
        "SES_DESTINATION_EMAIL": "${ses_destination_email}",
        "SUBJECT": "${ses_subject}",
        "BODY_HTML": "${ses_body_html}"
      },
      "End": true
    },
```

Now when calling terraform apply i'm getting this error :

> Error: InvalidDefinition: Invalid State Machine Definition:
>   'INVALID_JSON_DESCRIPTION: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR,
>   code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string
>   value

I tried to make the html content in one line like that :

```
<html><body><h1>ElasticSearch cluster started and ready</h1><p>The ElasticSearch cluster has started and ready to use</p></body></html>
```

and it works fine, but it's not great to read and maintain the file like that.

Is there way to solve that ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you have provided, it seems that the rendered template has a illegal character that needs to be escaped. The control character 10 is a line feed. So each new line needs to be escaped with a backslash. Did you create that html file in a windows application like notepad++ or similar? I would try creating it in VSCode or Linux editor like vim or nano.

As an alternative you can try to escape the line feeds using '\\n' or '\n' without the ticks, at the end of each line of text. I haven't run into this before, so I'm not exactly sure of the correct way to get Terraform to co-operate. Terraform marshalling of JSON can be difficult sometimes.

What I can tell you that is why you are getting a CC10 and it works when you place the information all on one line.

Comment: Hi, thank your answer, i'm using Visual Studio Code on Linux Fedora. I tried now to edit the file using Vi and i tried multiline i got the same error. 
I tried also to insert \n and \\n and at the end of each line and same thing.
By the way did you mean that : ?
<html>\n
<body>\n
....

Comment: No just at the end of lines inside the body of your message. For example <h1>ElasticSearch cluster started and ready\\n</h1>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Terraform v0.12 or are able to upgrade to it, you can avoid this problem by using the function [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/jsonencode.html):

```
resource "aws_sfn_state_machine" "start_cluster" {
  name     = "start-es-sfn-${var.environment}"
  role_arn = aws_iam_role.step_function_iam_role.arn

  definition = jsonencode({
    "SendSuccessEmail": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": lambda_notification,
      "Parameters": {
        "SES_SENDER": var.ses_sender,
        "SES_DESTINATION_EMAIL": var.ses_destination_emails,
        "SUBJECT": var.ses_subject,
        "BODY_HTML": data.template_file.start_es_email.rendered,
      },
      "End": true,
    },
  })
}
```

By using `jsonencode` you can let Terraform worry about the JSON encoding. It will see that the `data.template_file.start_es_email.rendered` value has newlines in it and will escape them automatically as `\n`. Unless there is a specific reason why you need to control exactly how the data is formatted, I'd recommend to always use `jsonencode` to generate JSON in Terraform, and not to use string templates.

Although Terraform 0.11 *does* have a `jsonencode` function, its is a much more simplistic implementation that will not produce a correct result for this particular situation.

Comment: this is a much more elegant solution. I'll have to keep this in mind as we convert our projects to v0.12~

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i'm already working on Terraform 0.12. I tried it but now i'm getting this error : Error: InvalidDefinition: Invalid State Machine Definition: 'SCHEMA_VALIDATION_FAILED: Expected value of type [OBJECT] at /'

Comment: I'm passing the entire template rendered file to the state_machine like that : 

definition = jsonencode("${data.template_file.start_services_template.rendered}")